# CSS text-overflow in a table cell

Tags: css

In a table, with css, I want to display the text of the first cell on several adjacent cells like the image below :

thanks in advance for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHC3q.png)

with this css the text has been clipped, but this is not what I wanted

```
td
{
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
overflow: visible
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

> The table-layout CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out
> table cells, rows, and columns.
>
> fixed
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
> subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can
> speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but
> subsequent cell content might not fit in the column widths provided.
> Cells use the overflow property to determine whether to clip any
> overflowing content, but only if the table has a known width;
> otherwise, they won't overflow the cells.

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed; /* <---- this makes the difference */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;  
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

td{  
 white-space: nowrap; /* <---- and this also */
}

td{
  border: solid black;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a very long text that should overflow the table cell</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```